# Delete cascade for foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_businessalbum` 
(
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`image` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`businessId` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`addedBy_userId` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
CONSTRAINT fk_businessId FOREIGN KEY(businessId) REFERENCES tbl_business(id) 
ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

But still whn I a delete a record from tbl_business the rows containing data involved in the foreign key relationship i.e from tbl_businessalbum are not deleted

Comment: 7 questions with no single accept. wow.

Comment: You might have also noticed that foreign keys are not enforced either.

Answer (score 4):

Somebody correct me if I am out of date, but the MySQL MyISAM engine doesn't deal with Foreign keys does it?

Comment: they http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html say only 'innodb'